# How to store properties with different languages in mongodb and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
var cvSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  alias: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 6},
  profitCentre: {type:Number, min:1000, max:9999},
  city: String,
  company: String,
  profession: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'profession',
    required: true
  }, 
});
```

The profession property is a reference. The profession can have one value, but with several languages. Is there any best practice on how to do this?

I came up with two options:

```
var professionSchema = new Schema({
  values: [
    {
      lang: {type: String, enum: ['sv', 'en']},
      name: {type: String, required: true}
    }
  ]
});
```

Option two: (en = english, sv = swedish):

```
var professionSchema = new Schema({
      en: 'String',
      sv: 'String'
    });
```

The first one is more generic, but I find it difficult to run easy queries (populate etc) on it. It's easier to run queries with the second one. Is there a right or wrong way here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see either of these being right or wrong and think you should use the solution that fits best with what you are trying to accomplish.

You might even consider checking out [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-intl) npm package to make things simpler.